# How to build a table of imported data from conditional data sources

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange, google-sheets-filter

I have many spreadsheets where data will be added manually and which are all identical. Let's call these UserInputSpreadsheets.

Inside each user spreadsheet are tabs with data which are also identical.

Let's call these tabs Data Input Sheets.

ALl DataInputSheets are identical.

Seach UserSpreadsheet has 1 compilation tab, which compiles all the data in the DataInputSheets. Let's call them UserSpreadsheetCompilationTabs

Here's an example

User Input Spreadsheet 1

```
fig.1
DataInputSheet 1
date      | name | value
-----------------------
1/12/2022 | Foo  | bar
1/13/2022 | Baz  | Quox

fig.1
DataInputSheet 2
date      | name | value
-----------------------
1/12/2022 | Burr | Bazz
1/13/2022 | Butts| Bums

UserSpreadsheetCompilationTab1 

fig.3
date      | name | value
-----------------------
1/12/2022 | Foo  | bar
1/13/2022 | Baz  | Quox
1/12/2022 | Burr | Bazz
1/13/2022 | Butts| Bums
```

Now imagine there are 10 of these Spreadsheets that exist and all are going to be compiled into a MasterSpreadsheet.

Here is what the MasterSpreadsheetCompilationTab should look like if we have 2 spreadsheets, a 2nd that you cannot see, and the first one included using the sample data above.

```
fig.4
date      | name | value
-----------------------
1/12/2022 | Foo  | bar
1/13/2022 | Baz  | Quox
1/12/2022 | Burr | Bazz
1/13/2022 | Butts| Bums
1/15/2022 | Grr  | Arr
```

However, the number of UserInputSpreadsheets is a variable quantity and will definitely adjust over time. So I need the MasterSpreadsheetCompilationTab to be able to adjust its output based on this.

Therefore I created a manifest that lists the URLs of the UserInputSpreadsheets. Let's call it the Manifest

It looks like this:

```
fig.5
Slots | User name | UserInputSpreadsheetURL
--------------------------------------
1     | Nickypoo  | https://agooglesheeturl...
2     | Bennyboo  | https://agooglesheeturl...
3     | Hoopadoo  | https://agooglesheeturl...
4     | -         | -
5     | -         | -
```

The MasterSpreadsheetCompilationTab needs to look at this Manifest and only display data that has a URL listed on this Manifest tab.

I think I'm pretty close with this function:

```
=reduce(
   importrange(Manifest!B3, "Compiled!A2:AE"), 
   filter(Manifest!B4:B12, isblank(Manifest!B4:B12)=false), 
   lambda(array, url, {
      array; query(importrange(url, "Compiled!A2:AE"), "select * where Col1 is not null")}))
```

However, it is only showing the first set of data in the first argument of the reduce function.

Essentially the MasterSpreadsheetCompilationTab looks like this if I use the sample data from above:

```
fig.6
date      | name | value
-----------------------
1/12/2022 | Foo  | bar
1/13/2022 | Baz  | Quox
```

I need it to look like fig 4.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please show an example of the source data using a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) together with a table that shows your manually entered desired results. You can simplify the scenario to just two or three columns. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Thnak you! I've heavily editing the question to use tables as you pointed out.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet where the issue can be reproduced. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce()` to merge several multi-row arrays into one taller array, like this:

```
=reduce( 
  importrange(C3, "Compiled!A1:AE1"), filter(C3:C14, B3:B14), 
  lambda( 
    result, url, 
    { 
      result; 
      query( 
        importrange(url, "Compiled!A2:AE"), 
        "where Col1 is not null", 0 
      ) 
    } 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: is the first argument supposed to be the starting array to be stacked by other arrays?

Comment: Yes. See [reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597).

Comment: Thank you! This function has me very close. The challenge I'm seeing is that I cannot push or append the newly queried array into the reduce accumulated array ("result").

Comment: Ohh, I see that the first argument in your reduce function includes the first result, and then the rest should build on that result. I was trying to append to an empty array to account for the possibility that there would be no data to begin with. But let's assume at least 1 source will work and it will be the first. The issue I see now is that only the base dataset is shown and not the data processed in the lambda.

Comment: I heavily edited the question to better help with answers. I think you got the gist of what I'm  trying to accomplish but I think you'll also see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Google Sheet formulas do not have a concept of a totally empty array. It is usually easiest to start with a single header row that lists column names, or a row that contains blanks (but has as many columns as the data.) It is unclear how the answer fails to meet your requirements. Please clarify.

Comment: that makes sense, that's very insightful! The array is not stacking for me. It only shows the first set of data in the array, not the rest of the imported data via the lambda function.